# Batch how to copy all contents of a file

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have done a TON of research on this topic, and I can't find an answer. Let's say  I have this as a file:

`@echo off
cls
echo Hello World!
echo %ALLCONTENTS%>Helloworldduplicate.bat`

but I want the copy to also have the code that makes a duplicate. For example,

```
@echo off
cls
echo hello!
pause
ENTER CODE THAT COPIES EVERYTHING, INCLUDING THIS LINE, HERE
exit
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong on [`copy /Y "%~f0" Helloworldduplicate.bat`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)?

Comment: I suppose the term you're searching for is `quine`. Look at [DOS Batch - Quine Collection](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsQuine.php) or [Quine in Batch](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5728). In quines it's forbidded to read files or external data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either as JosefZ commented or:

```
@echo off
cls
echo hello!
pause
type %0>Helloworldduplicate.bat
exit
```